# Security Concerns in Struts2 (Java EE) projects

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts

I am creating a web portal in java using Struts-2 framework. What are possible vulnerabilities in Java EE web portals and how can I can prevent my portal from them.Related links will be appreciated.

Comment: CSRF, XSS as with any other framework. Be sure to use the **latest** version, and to upgrade it quickly when new versions are out (due to security bufixing). Also note that J2EE is Java 1.4; since Java 1.5 it's JAVA EE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you make yourself familiar with the top 10 web attacks:
[owasp top ten](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project)

Then you regularly check the published vulnerabilities for your framework:
[struts vulnerabilities](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=struts&search_type=all&cves=on)

At some point there are tools which can automate parts of this.

Comment: Can you tell me those tools which can automate this ??

Comment: You can start with a web vulnerability scanner like the [OWASP Zap project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) which can be integrated in your build process.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main area:

1. Keep your struts framework up to date. Always check https://struts.apache.org/docs/security-bulletins.html . This is a must, when you are using framework, a security hole in framework means a security hole in your application.
2. Develop you own site secure as mentioned in https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project

Here are some tips:

1. If you are using `${}` in your jsp, please consider that they are not xss safe, you can make them xss safe as mentioned in http://pukkaone.github.io/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html. You can use `s:property` which is xss safe
2. If you are using ModelDriven consider that ModelDriven interceptor is blind! [Does the ModelDriven interface poses a security explot in struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337935/does-the-modeldriven-interface-poses-a-security-explot-in-struts2)
3. Consider that you can avoid some security issues by just setting your app with correct parameters in web.xml and server.xml instead of handeling them with struts, for example:

:

```
    <session-config>
           <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
        <!--This will prevent jsession url re-writing -->
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

4. You can use spring security with your struts. The spring security could handle some issues `session-fixation` and `csrf` without any code writing.