# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

So this is the case.. I am creating a web application using struts2 and hibernate. I am creating a change password page by which a user can change his password. But I am getting error as "`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`".. Below is my code and stack trace.

> //JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>H2H: Change Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <s:form action="changep">               
            <s:textfield name="empid" label="Emp ID" />
            <s:textfield name="uname" label="Username"/>
            <s:password name="opwd" label="Old Password"/>
            <s:password name="npwd" label="New Password"/>
            <s:password name="cpwd" label="Confirm Password"/>
            <s:submit name="Change Password" align="center"/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> //hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.100.25:1433;databaseName=db_h2h</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml" class="example.Login"/>
    <mapping resource="pass.hbm.xml" class="example.Pass"/>    
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

> //pass.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" 
           name="example.Pass" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" 
           select-before-update="false" table="masters.tbl_users">
        <id name="empid" type="int">
            <column name="empid" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="empname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="empname" />
        </property>                     
        <property name="newpwd" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="pass" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> //struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <package name="subin" namespace="" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="login" class="example.ShowLoginAction">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="pass" class="example.ShowPassAction">
            <result name="success">/changepass.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="dashboard" class="example.ShowDashboardAction">
            <result name="success">/dashboard.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="verify" class="example.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/dash.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/fail.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="changep" class="example.PassAction">
            <result name="success">/dash.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/fail.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/fail.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

> //POJO class(Pass.java)

```
package example;

public class Pass {
    private int empid;
    private String empname;
    private String oldpwd;
    private String newpwd;
    private String cnfpwd;

    public int getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setEmpid(int empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }

    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }

    public String getOldpwd() {
        return oldpwd;
    }

    public void setOldpwd(String oldpwd) {
        this.oldpwd = oldpwd;
    }

    public String getNewpwd() {
        return newpwd;
    }

    public void setNewpwd(String newpwd) {
        this.newpwd = newpwd;
    }

    public String getCnfpwd() {
        return cnfpwd;
    }

    public void setCnfpwd(String cnfpwd) {
        this.cnfpwd = cnfpwd;
    }

}
```

> //ActionSupport Class(PassAction.java)

```
package example;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class PassAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Pass> {

    Pass pass = new Pass();

    public PassAction() {
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("transx " + t);

        String hql = "UPDATE Pass set newpwd = :password WHERE empid= :id";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);        
        query.setParameter("password", pass.getNewpwd());
        query.setParameter("id", pass.getEmpid());
        int res=query.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Rows Updated: "+res);

        query.setMaxResults(1);
        t.commit();




        Pass p = (Pass) query.uniqueResult();
        if (p == null) {
            return "fail";
        }
        return "success";

    }

    public Pass getModel() {
        return pass;
    }

}
```

> //ShowPassAction.java

```
package example;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ShowPassAction extends ActionSupport {

    public ShowPassAction() {
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }

}
```

> //Stack trace

```
ERROR:   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Pass', table 'DB_H2H.Masters.tbl_Users'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
Severe:   187355 [http-listener-1(5)] ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: could not execute statement
Severe:   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:445)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:118)
    at example.PassAction.execute(PassAction.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.
Severe:   transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Pass', table 'DB_H2H.Masters.tbl_Users'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
```

I am a newbie to struts and hibernate.. So I request all your help.. I can give more information if needed.. I tried most of the solutions given in SO but none of them helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is clear, the password (old or new) is not set in your action POJO. So you are getting a **NULL**  which seems can not be inserted to you DB (for a not null constrain on you DB column).

The name of password tags does not match the name of your POJO, this allow the parameter interceptor and model driven interceptor fill your POJO. (Otherwise how struts could guss which field must be put in which property)

So change your tags as (do it for other tags too):

```
 <s:password name="oldpwd" label="Old Password"/>
 <s:password name="newpwd" label="New Password"/>
```

Please refer to:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/parameters-interceptor.html

https://struts.apache.org/docs/model-driven.html

Also please refer to [Does the ModelDriven interface poses a security explot in struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337935/does-the-modeldriven-interface-poses-a-security-explot-in-struts2)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Your answer updated my database but I got another glassfish error
 `Severe:   4995843 [http-listener-1(2)] ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE example.Pass set newpwd = :password WHERE empid= :id]`

Comment: This is a hibernate error not struts issue any more. I suggest you ask a new question on it. As far as I remember this happens when you try to select on an update query. _May be_  you should create a new query for  _uniqueResult_ call

Comment: By the way you should not update your DB and then select for duplicate, you should first make a select on your DB, the update if it is unique