# Update only single field in the form leaving other information unchanged in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, struts2

```
package org.entity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class BloodBankEditAction extends ActionSupport {
    BloodBankEdit bupdate;

    public BloodBankEditAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public BloodBankEdit getBupdate() {
        return bupdate;
    }

    public void setBupdate(BloodBankEdit bupdate) {
        this.bupdate = bupdate;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foryou", "root", "siddheshkk");
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            PreparedStatement st = con
                    .prepareStatement("Update bbinfo SET name=?,address=?,city=?,district=?,contactno=?,password=?,aname=?,email=? where code=?");
            st.setString(9, bupdate.getCode());
            st.setString(1, bupdate.getName());
            st.setString(2, bupdate.getAddress());
            st.setString(3, bupdate.getCity());
            st.setString(4, bupdate.getDistrict());
            st.setString(5, bupdate.getNumber());
            st.setString(6, bupdate.getPassword());
            st.setString(7, bupdate.getAname());
            st.setString(8, bupdate.getEmail());
            System.out.println("Executed");
            st.executeUpdate();
            PreparedStatement st1 = con
                    .prepareStatement("Update stockinfo SET name=?,city=?,address=?,contact=?,email=? where code=?");
            st1.setString(1, bupdate.getName());
            st1.setString(2, bupdate.getCity());
            st1.setString(3, bupdate.getAddress());
            st1.setString(4, bupdate.getNumber());
            st1.setString(5, bupdate.getEmail());
            st1.setString(6, bupdate.getCode());
            st1.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.validate();
        if (!(bupdate.getConfirm().equals(bupdate.getPassword()))) {
            addFieldError("bupdate.confirm", "Password doesnt match");
        }
    }

}
```

---

Here I want to update my existing information but what happens is whenever I update the data,  all the data related to specific code gets updated.

But I don't want like that, suppose I want to update only password, so in the form when I enter password, only password should be updated and other information should remain unchanged .

But this is not happening, if I update only one field other fields get blank . So what's the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the `ParameterNameAware`  and implement the `acceptableParameterName` . In this method you get the name of the input parameter and you can deiced to accept it by returning `true` or reject it be returning `false`.

A sample can be found at: [Does the ModelDriven interface poses a security explot in struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337935/does-the-modeldriven-interface-poses-a-security-explot-in-struts2)

Comment: how can i implement that ? can you give me the code or link where i can learn about that ?

Comment: No, it has not security exploit :-),  the latest version has hardcoded with excluded parameters, that has superior priority.

Comment: so give me the correct link where i can study ? anybody please ?

Comment: Here i want to update my existing information but what happens is whenever i update the data, all the data related to specific code gets updated. But i dont want like that, suppose i want to update only password so in the form when i enter password, only password should be updated and other information should remain unchanged . but this is not happening, if i update only one field other fields get blank . So whats the solution for this ?

Comment: No data is updated related to specific code unless you put a correct data. If you want to update only password, then you should create a query that returns only password for updating.

Comment: You can use `Update bbinfo SET password=? where email=?`, if you want to update the password only

Comment: that i know ,but suppose user wants to update contact number and doesnt want to update password or anything else then the above query wont work . Thats what i am asking is there any way where i can update only the felds which user wants to update leaving the rest information unchanged .?

Comment: Lets make it simple, please correct me. You have a form in your jsp the form has all fields password, email, city ,... you select data from DB populate the form and show the form to user. User may change email, or may change email and city or he may change only city, .... There is no, simple way, for you to find which fields are changed. You should assume that any filed could be changed by user and updated all fields. If you want to do it in hard way, you must re-select the data from DB compare it with data which user inserted, make a dynamic update statement and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I got what do you want, you want change the query that returns only one record for specified email. The email should be unique in the table.

```
PreparedStatement st = con
.prepareStatement("Update bbinfo SET name=?,address=?,city=?,district=?,contactno=?,password=?,aname=?,code=? where email=?");
st.setString(1, bupdate.getName());
st.setString(2, bupdate.getAddress());
st.setString(3, bupdate.getCity());
st.setString(4, bupdate.getDistrict());
st.setString(5, bupdate.getNumber());
st.setString(6, bupdate.getPassword());
st.setString(7, bupdate.getAname());
st.setString(8, bupdate.getCode());
st.setString(9, bupdate.getEmail());
System.out.println("Executed");
st.executeUpdate();
```